# Arquillian test won't run when code has java 8 lambda expression

Tags: java-8, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I have an Arquillian test that fails to run if either my test method or the EJB my test is invoking uses lambdas. The test doesn't even get far enough to run, looks like it fails on arquillian initialization. For example, putting this

```
Stream.of("one", "two", "three").map(String::new);
```

into my test method results in the following exception when executing as a junit test inside eclipse.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:165)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:102)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:161)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:165)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:102)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.ManagerBuilder.create(ManagerBuilder.java:77)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:62)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:161)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create and process manager
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:220)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:166)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:94)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:135)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:108)
    at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension.getDeploymentClass(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:78)
    at org.eu.ingwar.tools.arquillian.extension.suite.ArquillianSuiteExtension.register(ArquillianSuiteExtension.java:63)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.LoadableExtensionLoader.load(LoadableExtensionLoader.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fireProcessing(ManagerImpl.java:346)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.<init>(ManagerImpl.java:100)
    ... 22 more
```

I'm using Arquillian 1.1.8.Final and JBoss shrinkwrap resolver 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Removing the arquillian-suite-extension as a dependency fixed the issue, even though I wasn't using it

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eu.ingwar.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-suite-extension</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: What other dependencies do you have?  This was an issue w/ suite, but fixed by upgrading the reflections library.  See https://github.com/ingwarsw/arquillian-suite-extension/issues/22 as an example resolution.

Comment: thanks, forcing the newer version of the reflection library resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

To add to [John Ament](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577181/john-ament)'s comment, because it wasn't immediately obvious to me and this issue still persists:

When using `arquillian-suite-extension` you need to set the version of [org.reflections/reflections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections) to exactly 0.9.9 in your pom.xml. Neither a version higher or lower than that worked for me.

This is the entry required in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.9</version>
</dependency>
```